# How do you reliably serve images from a server?

Tags: node.js, image, file-upload

This has got to be a simple question, I know. But this problem is driving me insane.

I have an app that allows users to upload both images & files that can be up to 10 MB in size.

I'm using nodejs on the backend to handle them and am currently saving the base64 into a blob in the database(mysql). I figured this would be the issue, but I checked the database and it only had 3% average usage. So this wasn't the bottleneck. The EC2 doesn't go over 10% CPU so this seems fine aswell. NetworkIn averages around 200 MB per & NetworkOut averages around 100 MB.

I moved things over to an S3Bucket however fetching the images still goes through the server which is causing super slow loading times (like 10 seconds)

Should I just throw in the towel and move things over to imgur or does anybody know of something I can do or check?

Edit: Here's the monitor
[image]

Comment: Additional information request. 
any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Still need assistance? If so, post available info requested.